# Space inside French guillemets

Tags: polyglossia, csquotes, french

Here is my source:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\begin{document}
Je n'ai rien à dire --- mais je le dis bien: je suis un «beau parleur».

Je n'ai rien à dire --- mais je le dis bien: je suis un "beau parleur".
\end{document}
```

[image]
Polyglossia/csquotes manages the spaces inside « » well in the first example, but I have hundreds of page of source text with " " quotes. I don't understand why the inner spaces are missing when I use " ".

EDIT: I'm using XeLaTeX

Comment: I take it you're using XeLaTeX, as the problem you've identified doesn't come up when I compile your example code using LuaLaTeX. (I use MacTeX2016.) Any chance you can switch from XeLaTeX to LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @Mico yes I'm using XeLaTeX. I'll try with LuaLaTeX but I'm afraid it will raise other issues that had been solved with XeLaTeX :)

Comment: Do give LuaLaTeX a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More of a hack than a solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle[quotes]{french}
  {\mkfrenchopenquote{«}}
  {\mkfrenchclosequote{\nobreakspace»}}
  {\textquotedblleft}
  {\textquotedblright}
\DeclareQuoteStyle[quotes*]{french}
  {\mkfrenchopenquote{«}}
  {\mkfrenchclosequote{\nobreakspace»}}
  {\mkfrenchopenquote{\textquotedblleft}}
  {\mkfrenchclosequote{\textquotedblright}}
\DeclareQuoteStyle[guillemets]{french}
  [\initfrenchquotes]
  {\mkfrenchopenquote{«}}
  [\mkfrenchopenquote{«}]
  {\mkfrenchclosequote{\nobreakspace»}}
  {\mkfrenchopenquote{«}}
  [\mkfrenchopenquote{«}]
  {\mkfrenchclosequote{\nobreakspace»}}
\DeclareQuoteStyle[guillemets*]{french}
  [\initfrenchquotes]
  {\mkfrenchopenquote{«}}
  [\mkfrenchopenquote{\nobreakspace»}]
  {\mkfrenchclosequote{\nobreakspace»}}
  {\mkfrenchopenquote{«}}
  [\mkfrenchopenquote{\nobreakspace»}]
  {\mkfrenchclosequote{\nobreakspace»}}

\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\begin{document}
Je n'ai rien à dire --- mais je le dis bien: je suis un «beau parleur».

Je n'ai rien à dire --- mais je le dis bien: je suis un "beau parleur".
\end{document}
```

[image]